# Position of “respectively”

Tags: word-usage

Out of the 35% in favour, 33% and 11% respectively were from solicitors in medium-sized and larger practices.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/ko/dictionary/respectively

Can “respectively” be positioned as above? I was taught to say like this.

“33% and 11% were from solicitors in medium-sized and larger practices respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the adverb "respectively" requires two parallel lists of corresponding items. Therefore, both sentences are ok.

Comment: I was taught to use it after the second list.